# Notifications params only showing when app is in foreground

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to get the notification params in onCreate, but I only get the google.* fields.

My FCM Service:

```
 override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage?) {
    Log.e("Push", Gson().toJson(message))
}
```

This will show me when app is in foreground:

```
{
  "zza": {
    "mMap": {
      "google.delivered_priority": "high",
      "google.sent_time": 1565619574704,
      "google.ttl": 2419200,
      "google.original_priority": "high",
      "gcm.notification.e": "1",
      "gcm.notification.title": "New meeting",
      "from": "308737816494",
      "gcm.notification.booking_id": "339",
      "google.message_id": "0:1565619574708538%545adad5545adad5",
      "gcm.notification.body": ".....",
      "google.c.a.e": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

Notice  **"gcm.notification.booking_id": "339",** this is the field I need.

When app is in background or killed, and I click the notification, I have the next code in my launcher activity:

```
 private fun checkNotifications(intent: Intent?) {
        val bookingId = intent?.getStringExtra("gcm.notification.booking_id")
        Log.e("Push", "bookind id $bookingId)")
        Log.e("PUSH", Gson().toJson(intent?.extras))
```

The problem is here that I don't get any gcm.* filters, just google.*. And of course that bookindId is null.

```
{
  "mMap": {
    "google.delivered_priority": "high",
    "google.sent_time": 1565622016732,
    "google.ttl": 2419200,
    "google.original_priority": "high",
    "from": "308737816494",
    "google.message_id": "0:1565622016737416%545adad5545adad5",
    "collapse_key": "com.wolfpack.planetoffinance"
  }
}
```

Server sided code;

```
 def options
  {
    notification: {
      title: titles[notification.notification_type.to_sym],
      body: bodies[notification.notification_type.to_sym],
      booking_id: notification.booking_id
    }
  }
end
```

````
```def call
    @other_user = other_user

    response = FCM_CLIENT.send(registration_ids, options)
    notification.user.devices.where(uuid: response[:not_registered_ids]).destroy_all
  end
````

```
def call
@other_user = other_user

response = FCM_CLIENT.send(registration_ids, options)
notification.user.devices.where(uuid: response[:not_registered_ids]).destroy_all
```

end

Comment: Is this mMap data is passed by you in 'data' payload from server side?? Can u post that code (to send notification)??

Comment: No, is just the android representation. I've attached the server sided code.

Comment: If 'booking_id' is your field... Try to send in data payload instead of notification object.
Then get it in android side.